# google maps phone undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have following function to show markers on map and Info window .The window is showing all other information but showing phone is undefined

```
 function createMarker(obj) {

// prepare new Marker object
var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: obj.geometry.location,
    map: map,
    title: obj.name,
            icon:icon_url
});
markers.push(mark);

// prepare info window
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<span style="padding: 0px; text-align:left" align="left"><h3>' + obj.name+'</h3>'+ obj.vicinity+ '<br />'+ obj.formatted_phone_number + '<br />'
});

// add event handler to current marker
google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
    clearInfos();
    infowindow.open(map,mark);
});
infos.push(infowindow);
}
```

Like this

[image]

Comment: `but showing phone is undefined` what does this mean?  can you elaborate?

Comment: https://zahid-nisar.squarespace.com/testpage/# you can see here by selecting a place and then clicking on marker

Comment: It is clear that `obj.formatted_phone_number` is not there.  can you paste what `obj` contains?

Comment: I have tried that its not working

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged the `response` returns by the Google place API.

```
{
    "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 43.661981,
            "lng" : -79.38346900000001
        }
    },
    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
    "id" : "a7ebbb8b14235b329ca4408a9c4f4c53a5c8db7a",
    "name" : "Royal Bank - Yonge & Grenville", //------> obj.name
    "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
    },
    "reference" : "CpQBgQAAAImMPYKq40rk40T7fWXv_b4Zh-HbXKzu-hAuvJzZSTnjAk18ciFlmNK5N8IqZx8VC0W3xsutfVi0xu9czcykNjeEYY5AKHc883W31DLRdLqoRlQdpX9XM9FvTjQPJeoMvVpeirbPflBTx27DNUqvymOiUS54lmerDdCAaNoE4Xo3fmvASLs38NEQVfeGWX_dABIQGlBWE24OhThiuEwe4jhHcBoUrQFVy6J4pdGWvzsr4RJg0sIDjsk",
    "types" : [ "bank", "finance", "establishment" ],
    "vicinity" : "468 Yonge St, Toronto" //--------> obj.vicinity
}
```

This is a part of *`obj`* and it is clear that *it does not contain any **`formatted_phone_number`***. Therefore it returned **`undefined`**.

Hope you understood.

Comment: How Can I get other details ??

Comment: @ZahidNisar what do you mean other details?

Comment: like formatted phone number,formatted address and etc